# which tool should be used in order to measure performance of a program unit?

Tags: java, performance

i need to measure performance of my program unit. I am using hibernate as ORM tool. i want a tool that is capable enough to measure the time taken per method invoked and excluding the database loads???

Please help

Comment: i am currently using VisualVm as tooling, but it  itself takes a hell lot of time to compute the proper time lines... apart from this is there any other tool which can give proper time for the execution of the time,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what a profiler does. VisualVM is a free one, but if you want mroe detail as to the timings and behaviour of JDBC queries I suggest you look at YourKit which can anlyse the queries in more depth.

Comment: for op's concerns, i feel that visualvm will do just fine. it's memory and cpu profilers are excellent for analysing runtime behaviour of java applications.

Comment: It is definitely value for money. YourKit can analyse the behaviour of queries and other resources, not just how much cpu/memory is used where.

Answer (score 0):

JConsole is a graphical monitoring tool to monitor the Java Virtual Machine and java applications both on a local or remote machine.
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html

Answer (score 0):

for a quick and dirty hack, you can use http://www.clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html, a junit based microbenchmark framework. You can write your code, mock out (or even use a real database), and run it to get a benchmark. This benchmark is essentially good only for testing a single (or very few) methods, and in their specific uses, not a general profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear to me. Do you wonder which part of your application takes the time? Or do you want to observe the time a certain part of your code takes. In the first case use a proper file. VisualVM and YourKit are both fine profilers, I've used them before and found them very helpfull. In the latter case, I would try a tool like [Perf4J](http://perf4j.codehaus.org) which allows you to annotate a method and observe its average runtime, its standard deviation and other thing in realtime or afterwards.